# Is there a way to programmatically set an alarm that will fire even when in DND mode?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

An alarm should also be able to survive a reboot.

It'd good if opening alarm shows my app but it's not critical, just normal clock alarm is ok.

How can I do it in Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can do it in **DO NOT DISTURB** mode.

`DND mode` stops notifications, alerts, and calls from making any noise, vibration or turning up the phone screen or making flashing LED to flash.

It does not prevent them from happening, you will still receive notifications, but they will not bother you by making noises (audible or visible).

Without DND mode, you can fire a [localNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=windows) at a specific time.